# Max of a $f(x)$ when $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $$h(x) = f(x) + g(x).$$

If we know the value of $x$ where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are maximum, is there any possible way to find where $f(x)$ is maximum?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot say anything without knowing $f,g$ and $h$ or the relation between them. For instance, if all functions are differentiable, the maximum can only occur on $x$-values where $f'(x) = 0$. But $f'(x) = h'(x)-g'(x)$ so we would need to know when $h'$ and $g'$ intersect.

Even when we know the zeros of the derivative of $f$, we would also need additional information about $f''$ to know whether or not the critical point is a maximum, minimum or turning point.